# BSOD machine_check_exception in Windows 10 with secondary drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bsod, machine-check-exception

I just built a new PC:

MSI X99A Sli Plus
PSU Cooler Master V550
Intel i7 5820K
Corsair DDR4 32GB
Nvidia Quadro K2200
Samsung SM951 256 GB M.2 boot drive

I installed Windows 10 Enterprise on a Samsung SM951 M.2 (UEFI), and played with it for some hours with no problems.

Now I want to connect the hard drives from my old PC but I have this problem: after a few minutes into windows or even at boot, the PC freezes with `machine_check_exception` blue screen (I tried with an old WD 1TB disk, an old Maxtor 1TB disk and also with a brand new Samsung 850 EVO 1TB, these drives connected to different SATA ports each time and brand new SATA cables).

When I detach all the drives apart of course the boot drive, the PC will start normally.

Later I disconnected all drives but the new SSD (one SSD is M.2 boot disk, the other is SATA data disk) and I got into Windows, had the time to format the SSD data disk but then on the next boot I got the same problem.

Could it be some UEFI settings?
Should I have installed Windows 10 while having "Legacy+UEFI" in the "bios"?

Comment: Your UEFI and/or BIOS settings shouldn't (and probably couldn't) cause this.  Since this is a newly built machine, it's could basically be any of the new parts causing this.  My *guess* is either a power issue, or a faulty motherboard. To start, do the easy ones: ensure your motherboard BIOS is updated to the latest revision, and try a different, known-good power supply.

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to your desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to Onedrive, create a share link and post the link here.